# Command-Line: nano VS vi

Tags: command-line, nano, vi

What is the difference between the command-line text editors 'vi' and 'nano'?

Can someone explain this in detail and why many people prefer 'vi' over 'nano'?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you work with both editor or just jumped to ask the question before trying it?

Answer (score 3):

nano is a simple, easy to use editor that is especially popular among new users and users who hardly ever use a text editor at the command line. It's the default command line text editor in Ubuntu.

vi is a sophisticated editor for people who don't mind spending a few hours for learning how to use a powerful tool. It's popular among programmers, sysadmins and other people who spend a lot of time using a text editor.

You can quit vi using <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Shift-Z</kbd><kbd>Shift-Z</kbd> (that's not obvious from within vi).